# GCMRegistrar cannot be resolved when open gcm-demo-client by eclispe

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Still got many error message about GCMRegistrar after import GCM Demo ( gcm-demo-client ) and google-play-service_lib in eclispe.

did i missed some step?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Zqz.jpg

Comment: Did you say  that your project uses the google play services project ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis , Thank you for reply. I'm trying to open a demo app downloaded from http://goo.gl/N9Wa9P .. then i go the error message of GCMRegistrar. (Google Play services had set up already in this demo app project)

Comment: Right click on your project, select Properties, then Android. Do you see the google play service lib listed ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis , Yes i did..That's why i'm so confused .. http://imgur.com/By1gqlH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as your example : https://github.com/google/gcm

Step 1: import Android code, folder \gcm-client\, not \samples\gcm-demo-client\, then will see DemoActivity Android project.

Step 2:  add the Play Services library to your project, DemoActivity -> Proterties -> Android -> Library -> add -> google_play_services

P.S. The Google Play services SDK is saved in your Android SDK environment at /extras/google/google_play_services/

Step 3: add android-support-v4.jar, it saved \extras\android\support\v4

Step 4: modify project.properties, target min is android-10

Good luck!!

Comment: It works by following your procedure!! Big thanks! May i ask why should change target min to android-10 ? It shows configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in AndroidManifest.xml goes wrong.

Comment: if android-8, "regid.isEmpty()" in DemoActivity.java on my eclipse will error ; and android-9 other place will error. so if you can try it, maybe your eclipse won't.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of you have not put gcm library in your project. download it and add it to your project.
it can be found from here `Andoird_SDK_Folder\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist`

Thank you,

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. gcm library? Do you mean google-play-service ?? Because i only see this lib should be imported into project from google official site. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html